# How can I merge 2 dataframes in special conditions [R]

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a problem, it is complicated to explain, but I think not hard to solve, but I am a newbie in R... So hope you guys can help me.

I have two dataframes:

-The first one consists on a column with Portfolio1.

-The second one consists in 4 columns : Date, Portfolio2, Simulation, Value.

For each day there is a Simulation for each Portfolio and a value is obtained.

I would like to create a new table or dataframe in which I have the values of those simulations, for one day (this is not important, because the input data is of only one day) and for each portfolio. Therefore the table will have a column for each portfolio and a row for each simulation.

It is important to mention that there will be values in Portfolio1 that won't exist in Portfolio2. I will add a column with 0's in the new table.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I have tried to merge them unsuccessfully, using the comand merge.

The input data will be something like this:

```
Portfolio1
Port1
Port2
Port3

Date          Portfolio2      Simulation     Value
20150715      Port1           Simul1         12.6
20150715      Port1           Simul2         13.6
20150715      Port1           Simul3         14.6
20150715      Port1           Simul4         15.6
20150715      Port1           Simul5         16.6
20150715      Port3           Simul1         12.7
20150715      Port3           Simul2         13.7
20150715      Port3           Simul3         14.7
20150715      Port3           Simul4         15.7
20150715      Port3           Simul5         16.7
20150715      Port4           Simul1         12.8
20150715      Port4           Simul2         13.8
20150715      Port4           Simul3         14.8
20150715      Port4           Simul4         15.8
20150715      Port4           Simul5         16.8
```

And the resulting table:

```
        Port1   Port3   Port2
Simul1  12.6    12.7    0
Simul2  13.6    13.7    0
Simul3  14.6    14.7    0
Simul4  15.6    15.7    0
Simul5  16.6    16.7    0
```

The problem is that I don't know the exact number of columns. It will be determined depending on the given input files.

Comment: Show example input data and expected output.

Comment: I would say the `dplyr` package may help you here. Use `filter()` to filter cases (e.g. `filter(data.frame, Portfolio2 = 3)`) or maybe you can group your data frame and use the summary-feature (`data.frame %>% group_by(Date, Portfolio2) %>% summarize(...)`. Do you have some sample data and an output of the expected result? that would help being more precise with the answer...

Comment: If as @Tensibai points out you add data that can be directly used from your question (use `dput`) then in answering this actual data can be used.  Will improve the usefulness of the answers.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I should have provided the data. I can't provide actual data, but I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your question, but here goes.

To reorganize the data to have a row per simulation and a column per portfolio you can use `tidyr::spread` as in the following example:

```
> library(tidyr)
> df1 <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,1,2,3), p=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), v = c(111,222,333,444,555,666))
> spread(df1, p, v)
  x   1   2
1 1 111 444
2 2 222 555
3 3 333 666
```

To get the missing portfolio added the best I could think of now is something along the lines of:

df2 <- setNames(expand.grid(unique(df1$x), c(1,2,3)), c("x", "p"))

using the `x` column as the simulation ids, and `c(1,2,3)` as all possible portfolio identifiers.  Then using `dplyr` `anti_join`, you can get all combinations that didn't appear in the original:

```
df3 <- anti_join(df2, df1, by = c("x", "p"))
```

Add to this the values you want:

```
df3$v <- 0
```

and add as rows onto the original

```
> rbind(df1, df3)
  x p   v
1 1 1 111
2 2 1 222
3 3 1 333
4 1 2 444
5 2 2 555
6 3 2 666
7 3 3   0
8 2 3   0
9 1 3   0
```

Probably best to ignore the second part of my answer, this doesn't feel quite right.  The use of spread for reorganizing the data.frame I think is a good idea though.